# How to write this objective-c block in swift syntax?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

I recently switched from working with Objective-C to Swift and now I am facing  the following **objective-c** block.
I cannot figure out how to write it in **Swift (1.2) syntax**.
This is how the block is defined in objective-c:

```
formatter = ^(CGFloat value){

            // do something with value

            return "stringrepresentation";
        };
```

Could someone be kind and show me the correct syntax?

**ADDITIONAL Info:** the "formatter" value needs to be of type `ValueFormatter`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_151).

```
{(/*Parameters*/) -> /*ReturnType*/ in
    // Statements
}
```

So this block would be:

```
{(value : CGFloat) -> String in
    // Do cool stuff
    retun "aString"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That would look like this:

```
let formatter = { (value: CGFloat) -> String in
    // do something with value
    return "the formatted thing"
}
```

The type of `formatter` will be `(CGFloat) -> String`.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 2**

**Block Declarations**

```
var myCallBack:((Bool)->Void)? = nil
```

**Block sending back**

```
  self.myCallBack!(true)
```

**Block Receiving back**

```
myCallBack = { (isSuccess: Bool)-> () in
          //perform action you want to      
            }
```